# Responding to slack view_submission event with error object

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, slack, slack-dialog

I use ASP.NET Core 2.1 to build integration with Slack
Here is my modal in json format.

```
{
  "type": "modal",
  "callback_id": "send_sms",
  "title": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Send SMS",
    "emoji": false
  },
  "submit": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Submit"
  },
  "close": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Cancel"
  },
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "divider"
    },
    {
      "type": "input",
      "block_id": "phone_number",
      "label": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Enter phone number",
        "emoji": false
      },
      "element": {
        "type": "plain_text_input",
        "placeholder": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Phone number",
          "emoji": false
        },
        "action_id": "action_phone_number"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "input",
      "block_id": "message",
      "label": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Enter message",
        "emoji": false
      },
      "element": {
        "placeholder": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Message",
          "emoji": false
        },
        "action_id": "message",
        "type": "plain_text_input",
        "multiline": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So when user submit form, my .net core application recieves an view_submission event and if phone number has invalid format I want to response to this event with error.
Slack docs says that I should response with such json object:

```
`{
  "response_action": "errors",
  "errors": {
    "phone_number": "Invalid phone number format"
  }
}`
```

During debugging I found out that my app actually DO load json from file and DO respond with a string that contains this json. But a still get this error on my modal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPmfb.png)

controller method returns Task> object but I'm not sure that it's correct
So my question is:
Does anybody know how I should response to this slack event using .net core?
As far as I understand even if I have validation error in my .net core app and I want to return error object to slack, I should respond with status 200 OK

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly this question is resolved by returning

```
Content('json_string', "application/json");
```

Comment: While the question is for ASP.NET but If you are using Django and came here for the answer then you can use: 
return JsonResponse({
  "response_action": "errors",
  "errors": {
    "phone_number": "Invalid phone number format"
  }
})

don't forget to import: from django.http import JsonResponse